# How to pre-populate email address in B2Clogin.com new domain

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

In "***b2clogin.com***" new domain, When an AD user clicks the AD Button to login through (Open ID Login) it takes him/her to Microsoft Active Directory Login

> https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/...

In that "***microsoftonline.com***" domain, you can pass Login_hint parameter in order to pre-populate the username/email but how to do pass it in the b2clogin.com from the beginning ?

I was able to override javascript by that magic code (in the b2clogin.com page when the AD button got clicked):

```
          //adding email address to the AD login when redirected 
          $i2e._current_MS_Url_Generator = $i2e.getRedirectLink;                   // <-- Reference
          $i2e.getRedirectLink = function(n) {

            return $i2e._current_MS_Url_Generator(n) + "&login_hint=" + $('#logonIdentifier').val();                             
          };
```

but still that **login_hint** parameter wasn't passed over to **microsoftonline.com** page.

Answer (score 0):

Use the example here
[Pass parameter to Identity Provider on Azure Ad B2C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58875278/pass-parameter-to-identity-provider-on-azure-ad-b2c/58875628#58875628)

Except send a partnerclaimtype with the actual resolved domain name claim instead of a default value. If the domain name is always the same then just use the defaultValue approach.

Comment: Can you please elaborate in the steps to do that, I'm not custom policies expert. also does that require just a custom policy in the B2C or would it require changing the sining/sign policies to custom policy  ?