# Azure B2C custom layout redirect to domain hint but not taking login_hint

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, azure-ad-b2c

**This is my current scenario:**

I'm currently using Azure B2C with user flows. I create a custom layout for my login with some scripts that hide the IDP buttons and take the domain email to redirect to the proper IDP(like a user journey).

**The problem:**

I can redirect to the IDP by adding the domain_hint param in the URL but I can't add the email to that specific IDP so the user has to put his email again. I've been trying to add the login_hint param to see if it works but the domain_hint cause the redirection so the login_hint param disappears. This is really blocking me because we want to improve the user experience.

Also, I tried to perform the redirection in the script(by fetching it), extract the response URL, and then add the login_hint. This seems to work fine but I got a CORs policy issue that is not allowing me to perform the request as I expected

**Question:**

1. Is there any way to perform the redirection with the domain_hint and also add the email using user flows? Is it only possible with Custom policies(IEF)?
2. Is there any workaround for this CORs policy issue?

Thanks!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58875278/pass-parameter-to-identity-provider-on-azure-ad-b2c/58875628#58875628

Answer (score 3, accepted):

•   Yes, it is quite possible for your application to redirect to the identity provider of your choice as specified in the **‘domain_hint’ parameter**. `This query parameter provides a hint to Azure AD B2C about the social identity provider that should be used for sign-in`. Also, **along with the ‘domain_hint’ parameter, if you want that during the user journey, the sign-in name should populate automatically and the user should provide only password, then you can use the ‘login_hint’ query parameter** as shown below: -

***Example***: -

```
let loginRequest = {
loginHint: "bob@contoso.com"
extraQueryParameters: {domain_hint: 'facebook.com'}
}

myMSALObj.loginPopup(loginRequest);
```

•   **You need to know the domain name of your external identity provider** and you need to **pass these both the above query parameters in your application’s ‘MSAL loginPopup() method’**.

For a detailed understanding and configuration of the above, kindly refer to the documentation link below: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/enable-authentication-spa-app-options#prepopulate-the-sign-in-name

Also, **regarding the CORS policy issues, I would suggest you to please refer to the workarounds and troubleshooting steps specified in the documentation link below**: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-proxy/application-proxy-understand-cors-issues#understand-and-identify-cors-issues

Comment: I think this is pretty accurate but in my case, I was trying to add a simple JS script to my custom layout to do it.

Comment: @Yair Ruiz barbas.....good to know that. Do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot or else do accept it for helping other community members. Thank you.

Comment: this is the best answer I could find. In summary, it's possible but it will require changes from my app side. Currently, I'm working on moving into Custom policies that can be configured in a better way.

Comment: Kindly refer to this link: - https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples ; It might be of great help to you for creating custom policies.